# SVN - make commit invisible in history

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, code-formatting

I have SVN repository with quite large code base.
We want to reformat all code files with different code formatter. 
Every file will be touched in one commit (revision).

Question:

How to hide such commit? I don't want to display it neither in history nor blame SVN option.
Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe it would help to explain why it it is so important to hide it?  Did you know about the "blame previous version" option?  You can go back any number of versions on "blame", so doing a global change like this won't break the blame feature, if that's what you're concerned about.

That being said... the design of svn is very against the concept of "changing history".  You may want to look into git if that's the feature you really want. Git has a quite different philosophy on that.

Comment: I'm afraid of that every file in the project will be changed by one person. Do you think this is not a problem?

Comment: I understood that.  That's why I'm asking you why you consider that a problem.  It seems that part of your concern is that the "blame" feature will find that big commit for every line of every file.  While that is true, I don't see it as a problem.  Once you get to that commit you can do "blame previous version" and you will get beyond it and see "real" blame information from before that commit.  For later commits, you won't even get to that "big" commit.... it will blame the later changes.

Answer (score 0):

The default answer is that you **can NOT** *hide* or delete commits in svn. A commit that has been submitted, will remain there forever. This is the way it has been designed. It has its advantadges, but also its inconveniences.

There is a workaround, but it needs shutting down the server and hacking manually the repository with `svnadmin dump` etc.

Comment: It is technically possible to hide commits with help of access control (i.e., pat-based authorization). The user who uses http(s) or svnserve's protocol to access the repositories and does not have permissions to files modified by a revision will not see details of this revision and all changes made to those files.